# How to call a WebService with apache camel?

Tags: web-services, apache-camel

I'm trying to call a WS (SOAP/HTTP) using apache camel.

Let's say WSDL is located at

```
http://localhost:8080/TestWS/services/TestWS?wsdl.
```

I read http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html and some tutorials. But there the WSDLs are always local files (eg: file://local/wsdl/hello.wsdl).

Is there a way to reference a WSDL lying on a Tomcat for example?

I tried different things like

```
from("direct:in").setBody(this.body()).to("cxf:http://localhost:8080/TestW/services/TestWS?wsdlURL=http://localhost:8080/TestW/services/TestWS?wsdl")
```

but it's not working.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need the WSDL at runtime when invoking a web service? Is it for validation of your message?

You can achieve the very same thig without even knowing about the WSDL in advance using [Spring WS](http://camel.apache.org/spring-web-services.html). You need to construct a valid request though.

```
from("direct:start").to("spring-ws:http://localhost:8080/TestW/services/TestWS");
```